# Getting Warning Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance"

Tags: android

My app is working fine but I am getting this warning every time when I test my app in my physical device. I am not using any such third party library which can cause this type of issue. My LogCat view.

```
E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

Is this issue will cause some serious issue in future or not.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: that is not a  problem. It should not disturb you. It is some kind of firmware logging.

Comment: thanks for your time can you tell me what causes this warning and how can I resolve this.

Comment: this is nothing you can do about it. It is the system level log of your device's firmware, which was not removed by the device manufacturers. It won't hurt, and it is shown to you by the accident. Just don't pay any attention to it. It should not be resolved.

Comment: @VladMatvienko It would be great if you could post your answer for people to find the information quickly.

Comment: This might happen using any performance benchmarking tool.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is nothing you can do about it. It is the system level log of your device's firmware, which was not removed by the device manufacturers.

It won't hurt, and it is shown to you by the accident. Just don't pay any attention to it. It doesn't have to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm making wallpaper app I add service in manifest file my problem is solved.

```
    <service
        android:name="com.a.b.c.myapplication.WallPaperService.VideoService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="wallpaper"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/clock_wallpaper" />
    </service>
```