# Firebase Database not updating - error :xception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path:

Tags: java, android, firebase

my App runs but the database does not update, this is the error on the logcat:
03-02 18:41:43.160 15845-15845/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
Any ideas to fix this please, would very much be appreciated.

```
package com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 1000;

    private ListView mMessageListView;
    private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ImageButton mPhotoPickerButton;
    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private Button mSendButton;

    private String mUsername;

    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");




        // Initialize references to views
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
        mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        // Initialize message ListView and its adapter
        List<FriendlyMessage> friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item_message, friendlyMessages);
        mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

        // Initialize progress bar
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        // ImagePickerButton shows an image picker to upload a image for a message
        mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Fire an intent to show an image picker
            }
        });

        // Enable Send button when there's text to send
        mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
        mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT)});

        // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername, null);

                // Clear input box
                mMessageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;`enter code here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My friendly message class:

/**
 * Copyright Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat;

public class FriendlyMessage {

```
private String text;
private String name;
private String photoUrl;

public FriendlyMessage() {
}

public FriendlyMessage(String text, String name, String photoUrl) {
    this.text = text;
    this.name = name;
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhotoUrl() {
    return photoUrl;
}

public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
}
```

}

I had this piece of code but I receive errors with the "AddValueEventListner" see below:

```
// Read from the database
        mFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you post your code where you are setting data in Firebase?

Comment: I just posted it now

Comment: You've not written anything to firebase here... Your database reference is unused in this code here... Where are you setting the data?

Comment: Are you writing stuff inside your friendly message class?

Comment: The error you posted is not related to any problems you are having with Firebase.  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44041162/4815718

Comment: kushan I have posted the friendly message class above

Comment: Bob Snyder - I understand this, but I am trying to create a chat app, when I press the send button on the application, this error only appears then, moreover it shows as an error and not a warning