# How to fix java.lang.NoSuchMethodException Error in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

**Error message:**

---

> E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 =
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class
>   java.lang.String]

---

I am Using Kotlin in Android Studio and running this on a OnePlus 5, latest official release (which is Oreo 8.0 based as far as I can tell).when I did Convert code in java to kotlin then this error will happen, how to fix?

Comment: Can you give more details? I don't think framework error will cause you app to crash. I think you can ignore such messages

Comment: care to share code and that specific method, where you are facing this issue ?

Comment: @Umair I don't know which method and where I face this error in the app?

Comment: @streetFighter App is working fine.But in the log, this message will be shown in multiple times with red colour.so why it will happen in our app? I check in Debug mode also but it could not be shown which line it happen?

Comment: No it is not the problem in phone but rather in some other component app is trying to use, which manufacturer could not have implemented correctly.

Comment: @streetFighter I could not understand "which manufacturer could not have implemented correctly"...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44322568/5954246

Comment: Thanks for your help @streetFighter.